# how to create alias using XAMPP

Tags: xampp

how to create alias of a particular folder using XAMPP
example

http://localhost/abc -> http://abc.com or something like that....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into .htaccess and Apache mod_rewrite

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

P.s. I answered this because I knew you'd been awarded the tumbleweed and felt sympathetic as I got that the other day.